# Accessing Tor with Selenium and Chrome Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, tor

So I am currently trying to scrape a site on tor using Selenium but am unsure of how to access it. There are similar questions on this site but all are outdated and do not work. Hoping to get an updated answer now.

This is the code I tried but isn't working because I believe it is outdated:

```
from selenium import webdriver

torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\xss_selenium\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
PROXY = "socks5://localhost:9050" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\xss_selenium\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://juhanurmihxlp77nkq76byazcldy2hlmovfu2epvl5ankdibsot4csyd.onion")
```

How would I go about setting my proxies and accessing tor? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/DusanMadar/8d11026b7ce0bce6a67f7dd87b999f6b

Does this give you any luck?